# Access query, if two values exist in one column, omit one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a series of queries that generate reports that contain chemical data. There are two compounds A and B where A is the total amount and B is a speciated amount (like total iron and ferrous iron, for example).

There are about one hundred total compounds in the query result, and I need a criteria to filter the results such that if both Compounds A and B are present, only Compound B is displayed. So far I've tried adding a few iif statements to the criteria section in the query builder with no luck.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Table1.KEY_ANLT
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.KEY_ANLT)=IIf([Table1].[KEY_ANLT]=1223 And [Table1].[KEY_ANLT]=70,70,1223)));
```

This filters out Compound A but does not include the rest of the compounds. How can I modify the query to also include the other compounds?

Comment: It is always best to post sample SQL.

Comment: Or some sample data

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that you may have a table design that does not meet normal criteria.

Comment: Just added what I have so far. Table design is not the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I think you need a subquery with NOT IN (SELECT ...)

Comment: what is the table structure and how are you identifying the (A.B) pairs that need to be checked?

Comment: The key_anlt field is a column that contains numbers that relate back to a table with more information about each parameter. What I need is for the query to check to see if both 70 and 1223 appear in the key_anlt column and if both appear, only records with a key_anlt value of 1223 should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify some of the comments above, the problem here is you don't have (or haven't specified above) a way to identify values that go together. You gave 70 and 1223 as an example, but if you gave us a list of all the numbers, how would we be able to identify which ones go together? You might say "chemistry expertise", but that's based on another column with the compounds' names, right? So really, your query should use that column. But then there's still the problem of how to connect associated names (e.g., "total iron" and "ferrous iron" might be connected because they both have the word "iron", but what about "permanganate" and "manganese"?). In short, you need another column to specify the thing in common between these separate rows, whether it's element, ion, charge, etc. You would also need a column identifying which row in each "group" you would want to include in your query (or, which ones to exclude). For example:

```
+----------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| KEY_ANLT |    Compound     | Element | Primary |
+----------+-----------------+---------+---------+
|       70 | total iron      | Fe      | Y       |
|     1223 | ferrous iron    | Fe      |         |
|     1224 | ferric iron     | Fe      |         |
|      900 | total manganese | Mn      | Y       |
|      901 | permanganate    | Mn      |         |
+----------+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

Then, to get a query that shows just the "primary" rows, it's pretty trivial:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Primary='Y';
```

Without that [Primary] column, you'd have to decide how to choose each row. Perhaps you'd want the one with the smallest KEY_ANLT?

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM
    (SELECT Element, min(KEY_ANLT) AS MinKey FROM Table1 GROUP BY Element) AS Subquery
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON 
        Subquery.Element=Table1.Element AND
        Subquery.MinKey=Table1.KEY_ANLT
```

The reason your query doesn't work is that the WHERE clause operates row-by-row, and doesn't compare different rows to one another. So in your SQL:

```
IIf([Table1].[KEY_ANLT]=1223 And [Table1].[KEY_ANLT]=70,70,1223)
```

NONE of the rows will evaluate this as 70, because no single row has KEY_ANLT=1223 AND KEY_ANLT=70. Each row only has one value for KEY_ANLT. So then that IIF expression evaluates as 1223 for every row, and your condition will only return rows where KEY_ANLT=1223 (compound B).